# I want to Send Data Activity to fragment But InterFace Method Never Called

Tags: java, android

i implements my interface in Two fragments i want to send Data from Activity to both Fragments..when i do this my data send in Second Fragment not in First Fragment. it called  only Second Fragments interface method..not call first Fragment interface method i d'nt UnderStand Please Some One Help....

This is Main Activity

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentCommunication {
     TextView textView;
     ReceiveMessage receiveMessage;
     EditText editText;
     Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textAcitivity);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editActivity);
        button = findViewById(R.id.buttonActivity);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment1)!= null)
        {
            if (savedInstanceState != null)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
        SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment1, firstFragment, null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment2, secondFragment,null);
        fragmentTransaction1.commit();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                 receiveMessage.receiveMessage(name, 3);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
        try {

            receiveMessage = (ReceiveMessage) fragment;

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(fragment.toString() + " must implement receiveMessage..");
        }

    }
}
```

This is my interface

```
    public interface ReceiveMessage {
    void receiveMessage(String message, int from);
}
```

This is my First Fragment

```
    public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements ReceiveMessage {
    private View view;
    private TextView textView;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstfragment, container, false);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.Edit1);
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        return view;


    }

    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(String message, int from) {  // THIS METHOD NAVER CALLED WHEN I SEND dATA 
    FROM aCTIVITY
        if (from == 3)
        {
            textView.setText(message);
        }

    }
}
```

This is my Second Fragment

```
    public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements ReceiveMessage {
    private View view;
    private TextView textView;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondfragment, container, false);

        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        return view;
    }




    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(String message, int from) {
        if (from == 3)
        {
            textView.setText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time when you add a new fragment, the "onAttachFragment" of activity gets called again. So when you added the second fragment, you resetted the value of "receiveMessage" object to the interface implementation of second fragment.Hence you should rewrite your code as :

```
ReceiveMessage firstReceiver;
ReceiveMessage secondReceiver;

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    if (fragment instanceof FirstFragment) {
       firstReceiver = (ReceiveMessage) fragment;
    } else if (fragment instanceof SecondFragment) {
       secondReceiver = (ReceiverMessage) fragment;
    } 
}



button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();
             firstReceiver.receiveMessage(name, 3);
             secondReceiver.receiveMessage(name, 3); 
        }
});
```